# The checkbox in HTML is not working. Nothing happens when the checkbox is clicked. How to make it work?

Tags: php, html, css, input

HTML echoed through php. The html page shows a table which has checkboxes at the end of each row so that multiple rows can be seleted. Given below is the HTML to do so. The HTML is echoed through the PHP because this needs to be repeated for many number of rows:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['userdata'] as $row) 
{
  echo '
    <tr>

        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">'.$row['Symbol'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">'.$row['Name'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">'.$row['MarketCap'].'</td>
        <td style="vertical-align: 

        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="stocks[]" value="'.$row['Symbol'].'">
        <label></label>
        </td>                                           
    </tr>       
        ';
}

echo '<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; float: right;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select"/></td>
    </tr>
</form>';
```

The CSS is for the checkbox is given as:

```
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -2em;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 1em;
    z-index: -1;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label,
input[type="radio"] + label {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 2.4em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
    position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.025);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1.65em;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1.58125em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 1.65em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    content: '\f00c';
    color: #2e3141;
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note :

**Seems like you need to remove some code from your CSS to make it work..!**

Replace your first CSS Portion of the code with this one as :

```
 input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
    margin-right: -2em;
    opacity: 100;
    width: 1em;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Working JSFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/tL7uvgu0/2/